# Javascript adding li element value to the empty list if it is not existing

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have a problem in Javascript.I am adding new list items to the 'ul' elements and this list is empty at first and I do not want to add same values twice. When I write the if statement I get the exception because my list is empty so the result return null.
How can I fix this this problem?
Thank you in advance...

Html Codes

```
 <input type="text" id="the-filter" placeholder="Search For..." />
        <div class="list-container">
            <ul id="myList"></ul>
            <button  id="button">Click</button>
```

Javascript Codes

```
let newlist = document.querySelector("#myList");
const li = document.getElementsByClassName('list-group-item');
const button = document.getElementById("button");
const button.addEventListener('click' , listName);
const input = document.getElementById("the-filter");

function listName()

    const inputVal = input.value;
 
    for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
   
        if ((li[i].innerHTML.toLocaleLowerCase().includes(inputVal) && inputVal!="") || 
        (li[i].innerHTML.toUpperCase().includes(inputVal) && inputVal!="")) {             
            let newItem = document.createElement("li");
            li[i].classList.add("list-group-item");
            let textnode = document.createTextNode(li[i].innerHTML.toLocaleLowerCase());
            newItem.appendChild(textnode);

           if((newlist.children[0].innerHTML.toLocaleLowerCase().includes(inputVal))){
            newlist.insertBefore(newItem, newlist.childNodes[0]);    
           }

          }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're on the right track with event listeners and element creation, but your original code didn't quite seem to match your stated goal.

Here's a solution you might find useful, with some explanatory comments:

```js
  // Identifies some DOM elements
  const
    input = document.getElementById("my-input"),
    newList = document.getElementById("my-list"),
    items = document.getElementsByClassName('list-group-item'),
    button = document.getElementById("my-button");
  
  // Focuses input, and calls addItem on button-click
  input.focus();
  button.addEventListener('click', addItem);

  // Defines the listener function
  function addItem(){

    // Trims whitespace and sets string to lowerCase
    const inputTrimmedLower = input.value.trim().toLocaleLowerCase();
    
    // Clears and refocuses input
    input.value = "";
    input.focus();

    // Ignores empty input
    if (!inputTrimmedLower) { return; }
    
    // Ignores value if a list item matches it
    for (const li of items) {
      const liTrimmedLower = li.textContent.trim().toLocaleLowerCase();
      if (liTrimmedLower === inputTrimmedLower) {
        console.log(`${inputTrimmedLower} is already listed`);
        return;
      }
    }

    // If we got this far, we want to add the new item
    let newItem = document.createElement("li");
    newItem.classList.add("list-group-item");
    newItem.append(inputTrimmedLower); // Keeps lowerCase, as your original code
    newList.prepend(newItem); // More modern method than `insertBefore()`
  }
```

```html
<input id="my-input" />
<ul id="my-list"></ul>
<button id="my-button">Click</button>
```

Comment: Firstly thank you for your explanatory response. I understood my problem with your code.I want to fecth list items  and add to other list so your code work quite well for the first list actually I want to control my second list so it was my fault.I did not ask my question clearly.Thank you so much again:)

Answer (score 1):

If I understood the task correct, you need to add items to the list by button click.
If same item exists (case insensitive), then nothing happens.

```js
const list = document.querySelector("#myList");
const button = document.getElementById("button");
button.addEventListener("click", listName);
const input = document.getElementById("the-filter");

function listName() {
  const inputVal = input.value;
  const [...lis] = document.getElementsByClassName("list-group-item");
  
  const same = lis.find((el) => el.textContent.toLowerCase() === inputVal.toLowerCase());
  if (same) {
    return;
  }
  
  let newItem = document.createElement("li");
  newItem.classList.add("list-group-item");
  newItem.textContent = inputVal;
  list.appendChild(newItem)
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="the-filter" placeholder="Search For..." />
<div class="list-container">
  <ul id="myList"></ul>
  <button id="button">Click</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your recommendation. Yes actually I can add items to the list I do not have problem in adding but I do not want to add same elements. At the first the list empty when I add the condition I get the exception because list is empty I mean adding condition is inside of if clause when I remove if condition I do not get any exception but same elements are added twice

Comment: @Asu Please try my solution, it should work as expected.

Comment: yes I tried your code work quite well. I  understood my problem.Thank you:)